# VM is shutting down while I set a new iptables rule on Android to filter chromecast rtp streams

Tags: android

what I did is to set an iptalbes rule for chromecast screen mirror packets filtering on Android, but I find "Shutting down VM" after I typed in this command and hit enter.

Why would this happen...? And how to avoid this and make iptables rule work? Thanks!

Command I used:

```
su -c "iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --sport 2346 -m u32 --u32 \"26&0x000000FF=0x0000007F\" -j DROP"
```

And here are logs I captured with logcat:

```
I/SHELL   ( 7632): START1
I/SHELL   ( 7632): START2: 12578
I/SHELL   ( 7632): GETINPUT
I/SHELL   ( 7632): GETOUTPUT
I/SHELL   ( 7632): GETERROR
E/WifiStateMachine(  792): WifiStateMachine CMD_START_SCAN source -2 txSuccessRate=157.29 rxSuccessRate=235.30 targetRoamBSSID=c0:ff:d4:af:ab:0b RSSI=-46




W/iptables(12620): type=1400 audit(0.0:20): avc: denied { create } for scontext=u:r:init:s0 tcontext=u:r:init:s0 tclass=rawip_socket
W/iptables(12620): type=1400 audit(0.0:21): avc: denied { getopt } for lport=255 scontext=u:r:init:s0 tcontext=u:r:init:s0 tclass=rawip_socket
W/iptables(12620): type=1400 audit(0.0:22): avc: denied { setopt } for lport=255 scontext=u:r:init:s0 tcontext=u:r:init:s0 tclass=rawip_socket
D/AndroidRuntime(12634):
D/AndroidRuntime(12634): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
W/app_process32_o(12634): type=1400 audit(0.0:23): avc: denied { write } for name="system@framework@boot.art" dev="mmcblk0p28" ino=105876 scontext=u:r:shell:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:dalvikcache_data_file:s0 tclass=file
D/AndroidRuntime(12634): CheckJNI is OFF
W/app_process32_o(12634): type=1400 audit(0.0:23): avc: denied { write } for name="system@framework@boot.art" dev="mmcblk0p28" ino=105876 scontext=u:r:shell:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:dalvikcache_data_file:s0 tclass=file
D/AndroidRuntime(12634): Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
I/ActivityManager(  792): Start proc eu.chainfire.supersu for broadcast eu.chainfire.supersu/.NativeAccessReceiver: pid=12656 uid=10095 gids={50095, 9997} abi=armeabi-v7a
D/AndroidRuntime(12634): Shutting down VM
D/OpenGLRenderer(12656): Render dirty regions requested: true
D/Atlas   (12656): Validating map...
I/Adreno-EGL(12656): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: QUALCOMM Build: 10/24/14, 167c270, I68fa98814b
I/OpenGLRenderer(12656): Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/OpenGLRenderer(12656): Enabling debug mode 0
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 199/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 198/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 197/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 196/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 195/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 194/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 193/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 192/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 191/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 190/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 189/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 188/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 187/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 186/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 185/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 184/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 183/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 182/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 181/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 180/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 179/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 178/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 177/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 176/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 175/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 174/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 173/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 172/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 171/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 170/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 169/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 168/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 167/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 166/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 165/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 164/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 163/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 162/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 161/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 160/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 159/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 158/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 157/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 156/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 155/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 154/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 153/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 152/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 151/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 150/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 149/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 148/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 147/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 146/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 145/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 144/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 143/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 142/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 141/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 140/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 139/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 138/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 137/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 136/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 135/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 134/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 133/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 132/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 131/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 130/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 129/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 128/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 127/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 126/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 125/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 124/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 123/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 122/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 121/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 120/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 119/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 118/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 117/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 116/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 115/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 114/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 113/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 112/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 111/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 110/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 109/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 108/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 107/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 106/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 105/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 104/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 103/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 102/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 101/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 100/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 99/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 98/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 97/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 96/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 95/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 94/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 93/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 92/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 91/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 90/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 89/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 88/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 87/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 86/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 85/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 84/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 83/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 82/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 81/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 80/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 79/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 78/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 77/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 76/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 75/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 74/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 73/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 72/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 71/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 70/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 69/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 68/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 67/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 66/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 65/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 64/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 63/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 62/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 61/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 60/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 59/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 58/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 57/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 56/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 55/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 54/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 53/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 52/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 51/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 50/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 49/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 48/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 47/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 46/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 45/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 44/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 43/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 42/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 41/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 40/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 39/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 38/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 37/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 36/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 35/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 34/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 33/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 32/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 31/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 30/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 29/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 28/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 27/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 26/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 25/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 24/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 23/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 22/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 21/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 20/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 19/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 18/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 17/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 16/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 15/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 14/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 13/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 12/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 11/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 10/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 9/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 8/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 7/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 6/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 5/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 4/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 3/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 2/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 1/200 retries left
E/NetworkSession( 6982): Send datagram failed, 0/200 retries left
E/GCastSender( 6982): An error occurred during send in session 1 (-1, 'Send datagram failed.' (Operation not permitted)).
E/NetworkSession( 6982): writeMore on socket 135 failed w/ error -1 (Operation not permitted)
D/WifiService(  792): releaseWifiLockLocked: WifiLock{CastMirroringProvider type=1 binder=android.os.BinderProxy@25435344}
V/RenderScript(12656): Application requested CPU execution
W/AppOps  (  792): Bad call: specified package com.google.android.gms.chromecast_mirroring under uid 10089 but it is really -1
V/RenderScript(12656): 0xa1c09600 Launching thread(s), CPUs 4
W/AppOps  (  792): Bad call: specified package com.google.android.apps.docs.editors.slides under uid 10089 but it is really 10043
D/audio_hw_primary(  183): adev_set_parameters: enter: 0=;disconnect=32768
E/audio_a2dp_hw(  183): adev_set_parameters: ERROR: set param called even when stream out is null
D/r_submix(  183): out_set_parameters(): shutting down MonoPipe sink
I/r_submix(  183): in_standby()
D/r_submix(  183): out_set_parameters(): shutting down MonoPipe sink
D/r_submix(  183): adev_close_output_stream()
D/audio_hw_primary(  183): out_set_parameters: enter: usecase(1: low-latency-playback) kvpairs: routing=0
I/Converter( 6982): shutting down video encoder
W/GraphicBufferSource(  183): giving up limiting timestamp gap (pts = -1188265760)
W/GraphicBufferSource(  183): Dropped back down to Loaded without Executing
I/OMX-VENC(  183): Component Deinit
I/Converter( 6982): encoder (video/avc) shut down.
I/Converter( 6982): shutting down audio encoder
I/Converter( 6982): encoder (audio/mp4a-latm) shut down.
I/DisplayManagerService(  792): Display device removed: DisplayDeviceInfo{"CCDV": 1280 x 720, 60.0 fps, supportedRefreshRates [], density 213, 213.0 x 213.0 dpi, appVsyncOff 0, presDeadline 16666666, touch NONE, rotation 0, typ
E, FLAG_PRESENTATION}
I/JGCastService( 6982): disable TDLS
V/ActivityManager(  792): Display removed displayId=6
W/ALooperRoster( 6982): failed to deliver message. Target handler not registered.
^C
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can just ignore it.

Note the process IDs in the log messages.  Process ID 12634 is starting for the `am` command, which runs Dalvik bytecode, so it starts a VM.  It does some work, then shuts down.  I'm not sure why something is running `am`, but that's a different question.